# Is it a good idea to try get a position at a bad company in order to get experience and later get hired by a better company?

Tags: job-search, job-change, company-culture

If an inexperienced candidate is having trouble finding a job at a “good” company, would it be a good idea for them to apply at a “bad” company - one that is struggling to hire because of its reputation?

If they get hired, they could use their time at this company to build experience and improve their resume, thus making themselves more likely to get hired at a better company.

What would be the pitfalls, besides having to put up with whatever gave this company its bad reputation? Would this be a good idea?

Comment: In what field is this?

Comment: I think there is a flaw in your logic: *If the candidate has no experience, neither a good company nor a bad company will want to hire them, as they lack the experience*... a "bad" company will unlikely just hire someone not qualified for the job just because they are understaffed

Comment: What country are you asking about - this can viewed at differently form country to country? Having worked around the world, you could get insights that point you the wrong way without a country tag.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've decided to remove the question please do not add more comments or answer.

Comment: Define "good company" and "bad company".

Comment: If you have trouble getting hired at a company with a good reputation. The next best thing is to look for a job at a startup (that doesn't have a reputation, good or bad, yet).

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a *terrible* idea.

It's not just "bad reputation" you have to put up with in a metaphorical sense. Companies get a bad rep for a reason.

> If they get hired they could use their time at this company to build experience and improve their resume thus making it more likely to get hired at a better company.

If the company is really *that bad*, chances are you can't do this effectively (or you'll have a *really* miserable time doing so.) If turnover is really that high, chances are they also have staff shortages, so your workload is likely to be both astronomical and unsustainable.

...and all that's assuming that you can get hired at one of these "bad" companies at all. Just because they have a high turnover doesn't mean they'll be willing to take unqualified candidates.

Instead, find an internship at a *good* company, make a great impression there, and then see if they'll hire you afterwards. If not, then you've got the experience you need to move onto somewhere else knowing that you're qualified.

Comment: That's a good solution providing the internship is paid, or the OP can survive without pay.  But if they need a job, any job, an appropriate job at a bad company might be better than an unrelated job at a better company.  Might be.

Comment: +1 for the internship suggestion, really good idea if one has few experience in the topic. Even better if payed as thursday mentioned